# В аккоредоне работате только первый элемент. Подскажите пожауйста как исправить это?

Tags: javascript, accordion

```js
let estateOutContent = document.querySelectorAll('.estate_out_content');
let answer = document.querySelector('.answer');
let arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');


console.log(estateOutContent);
estateOutContent.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    answer.classList.toggle('active');
    arrow.classList.toggle('active');

  });

});
```

```css
.estate.out {
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 7px;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.rectangle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #232220;
  width: 100%;
  height: 387px;
}

.question {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  height: 53px;
  background-color: #FFFF;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 22px 0px 22px 17px;
  color: #232220;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
}

.answer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.answer_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  padding: 27px 56px 37px 53px;
  height: fit-content;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.arrow {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.arrow.active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.answer.active {
  height: 600px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.answer_title {
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="estate out">
  <div class="estate_text">
    <p class="main_subtitle out">Часто задаваемые</p>
    <p class="main_title out">ВОПРОСЫ И ОТВЕТЫ</p>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="Foto" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Почему северный Кипр привлектальное место для инвестиций?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                    </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="Foto" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как оплатить недвижимость?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                    </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="Foto" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как прилететь и нужна ли виза на Северный Кипр?</span>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                    </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="Foto" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как оформить недвижимость?</span>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                    </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="Foto" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как купить недвижимость в рассрочку?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                    </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="Foto" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Почему безопасно покупать на Северном Кипре?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                    </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- <figure class="bg-img-base" style="background-image:url(./images/images/.png); width: 100%; height: 500px; background-size: 100% 100%;"></figure> -->


</div>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) ищет по всему документу и возвращает первый в дереве.

Так как искомые элементы находятся внутри `estate_out_content` искать их тоже надо непосредственно внутри этого элемента. Для этого можно воспользоваться методом [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) у элемента внутри которого необходимо осуществить поиск.

Для этого достаточно перенести поиск внутрь `.forEach` и искать не в document, а в item:

```js
let estateOutContent = document.querySelectorAll('.estate_out_content');

estateOutContent.forEach(function(item) {
  let answer = item.querySelector('.answer');
  let arrow = item.querySelector('.arrow');
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    answer.classList.toggle('active');
    arrow.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.estate.out {
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 7px;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.rectangle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #232220;
  width: 100%;
  height: 387px;
}

.question {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  height: 53px;
  background-color: #FFFF;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 22px 0px 22px 17px;
  color: #232220;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
}

.answer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.answer_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  padding: 27px 56px 37px 53px;
  height: fit-content;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.arrow {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.arrow.active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.answer.active {
  height: 600px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.answer_title {
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="estate out">
  <div class="estate_text">
    <p class="main_subtitle out">Часто задаваемые</p>
    <p class="main_title out">ВОПРОСЫ И ОТВЕТЫ</p>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Почему северный Кипр привлектальное место для инвестиций?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как оплатить недвижимость?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как прилететь и нужна ли виза на Северный Кипр?</span>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как оформить недвижимость?</span>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как купить недвижимость в рассрочку?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Почему безопасно покупать на Северном Кипре?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Чтобы открытым был только один элемент достаточно при открытии - закрыть предыдущие.

С помощью [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) получить список всех активных и при клике удалить классы у нужных элементов:

```js
let estateOutContent = document.querySelectorAll('.estate_out_content');
let actives = document.getElementsByClassName('active');

estateOutContent.forEach(function(item) {
  let answer = item.querySelector('.answer');
  let arrow = item.querySelector('.arrow');
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var i = actives.length; i-- > 0;) {
      var a = actives[i];
      if (a !== answer && a !== arrow) { // если активными были не выбранные элементы
        a.classList.remove('active'); // просто убираем класс active
      }
    }
    answer.classList.toggle('active');
    arrow.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.estate.out {
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 7px;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.rectangle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #232220;
  width: 100%;
  height: 387px;
}

.question {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  height: 53px;
  background-color: #FFFF;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 22px 0px 22px 17px;
  color: #232220;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
}

.answer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.answer_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  padding: 27px 56px 37px 53px;
  height: fit-content;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.arrow {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.arrow.active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.answer.active {
  height: 600px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.answer_title {
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="estate out">
  <div class="estate_text">
    <p class="main_subtitle out">Часто задаваемые</p>
    <p class="main_title out">ВОПРОСЫ И ОТВЕТЫ</p>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Почему северный Кипр привлектальное место для инвестиций?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как оплатить недвижимость?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как прилететь и нужна ли виза на Северный Кипр?</span>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как оформить недвижимость?</span>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как купить недвижимость в рассрочку?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Почему безопасно покупать на Северном Кипре?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а подскажите еще пожалуйста как сделать remove у активного класса при нажатии на другой, чтобы не открывалось большой одной панели в аккордеоне?

Comment: @БизонЛазарев нужно взять все элементы с классом active и снять его

Answer (score 0):

Не работает, потому что на странице несколько блоков с классом `answer`, а в переменную записан самый первый. Такая же проблема и с `arrow`. Для исправления нужно производить поиск всех элементов с этим классом на странице с помощью `querySelectorAll`. В `forEach` к `answer` и `arrow` можно обращаться по index:

```js
let estateOutContent = document.querySelectorAll('.estate_out_content');
let answer = document.querySelectorAll('.answer');
let arrow = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');

estateOutContent.forEach(function(item, index){

  item.addEventListener('click', function() {

    let allActive = document.querySelectorAll('.active'); //Если происходит клик, то находим все элементы с классом active

    for (let i = 0; i < allActive.length; i++) { //Удаляем у всех найденных элементов класс active
      allActive[i].classList.remove('active');
    }

    if (!item.contains(allActive[0])) { //Выполняется, если у элемента нет дочерних элементов с классом active

      answer[index].classList.add('active');
      arrow[index].classList.add('active');
    }
  }); 
});
```

```css
.estate.out {
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 7px;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.rectangle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #232220;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 387px;
}

.question {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  height: 53px;
  background-color: #FFFF;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 22px 0px 22px 17px;
  color: #232220;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal; 
}

.answer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  height:0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.answer_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  padding: 27px 56px 37px 53px;
  height:fit-content;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.arrow {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.arrow.active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.answer.active {
  height :600px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.answer_title {
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="estate out">
  <div class="estate_text">
    <p class="main_subtitle out">Часто задаваемые</p>
    <p class="main_title out">ВОПРОСЫ И ОТВЕТЫ</p>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="→" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Почему северный Кипр привлектальное место для инвестиций?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="→" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как оплатить недвижимость?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="→" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как прилететь и нужна ли виза на Северный Кипр?</span>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="→" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как оформить недвижимость?</span>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="→" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Как купить недвижимость в рассрочку?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="estate_out_content">
    <div class="question">
      <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="→" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
      <span>Почему безопасно покупать на Северном Кипре?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="answer_content">
        <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
        <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
        <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
        <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
        <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
        <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: плохо называть параметр `id` - когда он им не является, может к путанице приводить

Comment: Спасибо большое, а подскажите еще пожалуйста как сделать remove у активного класса при нажатии на другой, чтобы не открывалось большой одной панели в аккордеоне?

Comment: @БизонЛазарев изменил код, теперь активна только одна панель

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает!

Comment: @БизонЛазарев рад был помочь, отметьте пожалуйста ответ как принятый

Comment: `if (allActive !== undefined) {` - это условие всегда `true`, потому что allActive,  как результат querySelectorAll - не может быть `undefined`

Comment: Почему-то решил, что эффект будет как у querySelector, спасибо за поправку